# Чтение xml файла в приложении winform(C#)

Tags: c#, xml, xmlparser

Необходимо считать данные с xml файла.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Diagram xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Elements>
    <HeatingPanel Id="0" Name="ЩУЭ-1" Location="400;-150" Temperature="4" IsInAlarm="true" IsEntryAutomateOn="0" IsNetworkOn="0" IsPowerOn="0" IsOnUps="-1" />
    <HeatingLine Id="1" Name="JB1" Location="238,8099;-39,37645" Temperature="-8" ParentId="0" State="Warning" />
    <Sensor Id="2" Name="TD1" Location="191,2572;-23,92546" Temperature="22" >
```

Разобрав файл, я создал три класса `Heating_Panel`, `Heating_Line`, `Sensor`. Далее на `Form1` я пишу метод считывания элементов файла. Вот тут у меня возникла проблема. Мне надо считывать файл и одновременно проверять значение имени и исходя из этого парсить. Допустим если `name="ЩУЭ"` то парсить соответственно `Heating_Panel`. Если `name = "JB"` то парсить `Heatinп_Line`.Не понимаю как это сделать.

```
private void LoadHeating_Panel()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("Test.xml");

        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild.ChildNodes)
        {
            int id = int.Parse(node["Id"].InnerText);
            string name = node.Attributes[1].Value;
            double location = double.Parse(node["Location"].InnerText);
            double temperature = double.Parse(node["Temperature"].InnerText);
            bool isonalarm = bool.Parse(node["IsOnAlarm"].InnerText);
            int isentryautomateon = int.Parse(node["IsEntryAutomateOn"].InnerText);
            int isnetwork = int.Parse(node["IsNetwork"].InnerText);
            int poweron = int.Parse(node["PowerOn"].InnerText);
            int isonups = int.Parse(node["IsOnUps"].InnerText);
        }
    }
```

Сделал парсинг в ручную и только для одного класса.А мне надо сделать парсинг всего файла целиком.Не хватает знаний.

Comment: Переделайте структуру записей под задачу.

Comment: Все проверки, сортировки, выборки надо делать после парсинга. Читаем файл, парсим, затем ищем и выдергиваем то, что надо.

Comment: Выбрать по имени  не проблема. На ментаните гляньте, там с примерами.

Comment: Чтение xml файла как в приложении winform, так и в любом другом случае будет одинаково, есть как минимум три способа с разными целями: 1)XmlDocument (аналог COM XmlDocument библиотеки) полезная ф-ция SelectSingleNode, 2)XmlReader (для особо сложного разбора), и 3)сериализация.

Answer (score 1):

Содержимое файла xml как в вопросе, только нужно добавить закрывающие теги.
[image: пример работы]

Собственно класс для парсинга такого файла

```
public class XmlService
{
    public static Elements GetElements(string pathToFile)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathToFile)) return null;
        if (!File.Exists(pathToFile)) return null;

        Elements result = ReadAndGetElements(pathToFile);

        return result;
    }

    private static Elements ReadAndGetElements(string pathToFile)
    {
        Elements result = new Elements();

        try
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load(pathToFile);
            var hLines = doc.Descendants("Elements").Elements("HeatingLine").ToList();
            var hPanels = doc.Descendants("Elements").Elements("HeatingPanel").ToList();
            var sensors = doc.Descendants("Elements").Elements("Sensor").ToList();

            ParseHeatingLines(result, hLines);
            ParseHeatingPanels(result, hPanels);
            ParseSensors(result, sensors);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Ошибка чтения и парсинга файла: {ex.Message}");
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static void ParseHeatingLines(Elements result, List<XElement> hLines)
    {
        foreach (var lineXml in hLines)
        {
            int id;
            string name;
            double[] locations;
            double temperature;
            ParseBaseProperties(lineXml, out id, out name, out locations, out temperature);

            int parentId = Int32.Parse(lineXml.Attribute("ParentId").Value);
            string state = lineXml.Attribute("State").Value;

            var line = new HeatingLine
            {
                Id = id,
                Name = name,
                Locations = locations,
                Temperature = temperature,
                ParentId = parentId,
                State = state
            };

            result.HeatingLines.Add(line);
        }
    }

    private static void ParseHeatingPanels(Elements result, List<XElement> hPanels)
    {
        foreach (var panelXml in hPanels)
        {
            int id;
            string name;
            double[] locations;
            double temperature;
            ParseBaseProperties(panelXml, out id, out name, out locations, out temperature);

            bool isOnAlarm = Boolean.Parse(panelXml.Attribute("IsInAlarm").Value);
            int isEntryAutomateOn = Int32.Parse(panelXml.Attribute("IsEntryAutomateOn").Value);
            int isNetworkOn = Int32.Parse(panelXml.Attribute("IsNetworkOn").Value);
            int isPowerOn = Int32.Parse(panelXml.Attribute("IsPowerOn").Value);
            int isOnUps = Int32.Parse(panelXml.Attribute("IsOnUps").Value);

            var panel = new HeatingPanel
            {
                Id = id,
                Name = name,
                Locations = locations,
                Temperature = temperature,
                IsOnAlarm = isOnAlarm,
                IsEntryAutomateOn = isEntryAutomateOn,
                IsNetworkOn = isNetworkOn,
                IsPowerOn = isPowerOn,
                IsOnUps = isOnUps
            };

            result.HeatingPanels.Add(panel);
        }
    }

    private static void ParseSensors(Elements result, List<XElement> sensors)
    {
        foreach (var sensorXml in sensors)
        {
            int id;
            string name;
            double[] locations;
            double temperature;
            ParseBaseProperties(sensorXml, out id, out name, out locations, out temperature);

            var sensor = new Sensor
            {
                Id = id,
                Name = name,
                Locations = locations,
                Temperature = temperature
            };

            result.Sensors.Add(sensor);
        }
    }

    private static void ParseBaseProperties(XElement sensorXml, out int id, out string name, out double[] locations, out double temperature)
    {
        id = Int32.Parse(sensorXml.Attribute("Id").Value);
        name = sensorXml.Attribute("Name").Value;
        string[] strLocs = sensorXml.Attribute("Location")
                                    .Value
                                    .Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        locations = new double[strLocs.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < locations.Length; i++)
        {
            locations[i] = double.Parse(strLocs[i]);
        }
        temperature = double.Parse(sensorXml.Attribute("Temperature").Value);
    }
}
```

использование класса

```
_elements = XmlService.GetElements(_openFileDialog.FileName);
```

вот классы для сбора информации

```
public abstract class BaseElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double[] Locations { get; set; }
    public double Temperature { get; set; }
}

public class HeatingLine : BaseElement
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class HeatingPanel : BaseElement
{
    public bool IsOnAlarm { get; set; }
    public int IsEntryAutomateOn { get; set; }
    public int IsNetworkOn { get; set; }
    public int IsPowerOn { get; set; }
    public int IsOnUps { get; set; }
}

public class Sensor : BaseElement
{
}

public class Elements
{
    public List<HeatingLine> HeatingLines { get; set; } = new List<HeatingLine>();
    public List<HeatingPanel> HeatingPanels { get; set; } = new List<HeatingPanel>();
    public List<Sensor> Sensors { get; set; } = new List<Sensor>();
}
```

Пример можно качнуть [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/1S3HXcz8IqfBVQ)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!Буду разбираться с кодом.С наглядным примером гораздо проще.